# MongoDB Map Property 'new' in findAndModify using FindOneAndUpdateOptions class C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to implement a `getNextSequence` function for mongoDB explain on this  [Link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) I'm using the lattes C# driver but I not sure how to map  the `new : true` property in the [`FindOneAndUpdateOptions`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindOneAndUpdateOptions_2.htm)

MongoDB Code

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true,
            upsert: true
          }
   );

   return ret.seq;
}
```

C# Code

```
    public async Task<long> GetNextObjectSequenceAsync(string objectName)
    {
        var collection = this.Context.GetCollection<ObjectSequence>("Counters");
        var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<ObjectSequence>().Where(x => x.Name == objectName);
        var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<ObjectSequence, ObjectSequence>() { IsUpsert = true };
        var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<ObjectSequence>().Inc(x => x.Sequence, 1);

        ObjectSequence seq = await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync<ObjectSequence>(filter, update, options);

        return seq.Sequence;

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FindOneAndUpdateOptions` has `ReturnDocument` enum where

> ReturnDocument.Before   =    'new':false
>
> ReturnDocument.After    =    'new':true

In your case options should be:

```
var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<ObjectSequence, ObjectSequence>() { ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After, IsUpsert = true };
```